# RegEx to match words exactly n characters long but also contain a specific letter?

Tags: regex, grep, match, contains

I have long list of lower-case countries (e.g. bali, united kingdom etc)

How do I match all words in it that are exactly 9 letters long and that also contain the letter 'i'?

I've got this so far for the first part:

```
\b\w{9}\b
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:

So I was able to make this:

```
\b(?=.*i.*)\w{9}\b
```

but it does not work with `grep -E '\b(?=.*i.*)\w{9}\b' countries.txt`...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Paul's response works fine if there is no space in it. What should happen with countries like San Marino (9 letters + space, 10 overall) and Sri Lanka (8 letters and a space, 9 overall)? Should any of those also match?

Comment: Which environment are you using? Are you getting an error? Does it support positive lookahead?

Comment: `-E` means ERE, which doesn't support lookarounds, non-greedy, etc... if you are using `GNU grep` and `PCRE` is available, then try, `grep -wP '(?=\w*i)\w{9}'` (but it won't work for countries with non-word characters like spaces)

Comment: To match a single word using word characters that is 9 characters long and contains an `i` you could use `grep -Po '\b(?=\w{9}\b)\w*i\w*\b'`

Comment: You need to provide more details when you ask questions. For example, I am not able to tell - are the countries shown one per line? Or in a single line? What do you mean by "nine letters" when country names may contain non-letters, like spaces or hyphens (Guinea-Bissau for example)?

Comment: Cranfield's profile says "Last seen May 15", so I guess he's not worried anymore about this and will not reply to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a positive lookahead for checking the number of chars and then check whether there is an i within.

```
(?=^[\w\s]{9}$).*i.*
```

Comment: This works quite good, except if there is a space in the country. I asked about this in the question (I don't know if a space counts as a letter or not).

Comment: Thanks, that's true! I allowed whitespace characters now. This actually won't work correctly if there is a whitespace in the beginning or end, but since it's a list it's probably trimmed and it shouldn't matter. Probably it would even work in that case if 'any character' is allowed.

Comment: How did you determine that the input file shows countries one per line?

Comment: Because Cranfield is talking about a long list. They are obviously not separated by a space, because otherwise it wouldn't be possible to filter countries like the United Kingdom. In any other case it's possible to handle each country seperatly.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't match with a sigle regex, you should attempts with two or more. In this statements, grep checks for the length and general character, then for i.

`grep -E '(\w|\s){9}' regex.txt | grep -E 'i'`

if you you are looking for a bit more strictness:

`grep -E '(\w|\s){9}' regex.txt | grep -E 'i' | grep -E '\w+(\s\w+)*'`

Comment: Now the letter `i` is optional, so it's still matching countries without it.

Comment: I added the 'i' at the beginning

Comment: I edited my comment above. Please, do at least a minimal validation before posting an answer.

Comment: Your execution is poor. For example, the current version has an alternation, and the quantifier `{9}`, but the quantifier applies only to nine spaces, not to nine word characters. The regexp must also be anchored at word boundaries. None of that, though, detracts from the correct approach: pipe two `grep` calls, they will work on the stream almost at the same time. No point in torturing the regex to cram both requirements into a single regex. +1 for the right approach.

Comment: @mathguy I check with 'Sri Lanka' and all goes well; the 'Sri Lanka'  string haven't 9 spaces so character  limit applies to the whole alternation. If I would to write a more strict regex I have to write a very complex regex because nations  haven't a well defined pattern like  car plat, e-mail or ip address. I assumed that the input file contains a well written list of nations. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @mathguy I added parenthesys to the regex.